# How to assign substring to a variable using regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract the language code from a url (e.g: /en/blog/first-post/) with this expression `[^/]\w{1}` and it works. What I need is to assign it to a variable `language_code = re.match('[^/]\w{1}')` However, this doesn't work because I don't want to provide a string to match to as an argument. I just want to get two letters from the string.

Comment: What do you mean by "don't want to provide a string to match to as an argument"?

Answer (score -1):

at the REPL:

```
>>> import re
>>> url_string = "/en/blog/first-post/"
>>> re.search('[^/]\w{1}', url_string)[0]
'en'
```